# Show and hide banner admob for a custom time

Tags: android, admob

This is my code and it is working perfectly:

```
   AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
   AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
   mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

However, I want my banner to show for a certain amount of seconds and then hide, for showing again later.
What is the best way to do it? Thanks!!

Comment: Let us know what you have tried and where you are struggling.

Comment: You can use a timer and an a handler to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timer and hide the entire ad layout after the timeout after it is displayed.

This is the easiest way to achieve your requirement.